# How to specify the user and group for service resource in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I have an init.d script that starts a particular service. In order to start it , I have used a service resource in chef recipe. However when the recipe runs it starts the service as a root user. How can I make sure that the service starts with a specific non root user.

I don't think it is recommended to use execute resource to start a particular service and explicitly specify the user attribute.

Please suggest how to start the service as non root user using chef service resource.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be handled by your init script or init system, not Chef. Assuming you mean normal sys-v init scripts, they generally either start the process as root and then the daemon and let it drop privs itself, or use something like `start-stop-daemon` which takes a `--user` argument. Other systems like supervisord make this an explicit field in the program description.